# Facebook login using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm going insane!

I have been trying to get the Facebook Login pop up to appear on my website using the Facebook Javascript API.

I've followed the tutorial multiple times but the login will not appear in the pop up and if I follow the login process through it ens up logging me in and not redirecting me back to my website. Once I'm back at my site I'm logged in and it works fine.

I have tried multiple variations of the below code (too many to write them all):

```
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '123456789012345',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
            showLogoutOption(); // This shows the logout option
        }
        else {
            showLoginOption(); // This shows the login option
            console.log('Not logged in');
        }
    });


    $('#loginOption').click(function() {
        FB.login(); // When the login option is clicked -> login        
    });

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I've also used the code under quickstart [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

So I can login, and I can access the FB graph API and pull data, and I can logout. What I can't do is have a login that provides a good customer experience.

Note: I am using Firefox (have tried it on Chrome which quickly flashes up a dialog box then disappears again, logging the user in but not refreshing the page).

If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
(function(win, doc) {
  var declined_perms = [];
  var PERMISSIONS = ['email', 'user_friends', 'user_photos', 'publish_actions'];
  var APP_ID = 'Your API Key';
  win.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: APP_ID,
      xfbml: true,
      cookie: true,
      status: true,
      version: 'v2.0'
    });
    afterFBASYNLoaded();
  };
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(doc, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  var afterLoginBtnClick = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      afterLoginStatus(response);
    }, {
      scope: PERMISSIONS.join()
    });
  };
  var afterLoginBtnReAuthClick = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      afterLoginStatus(response);
    }, {
      scope: declined_perms.join(),
      auth_type: 'rerequest'
    });
  };
  var hideAll = function() {
    $("#loginSection").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#loginSectionReAuth").fadeOut("fast");
  };
  var afterFBASYNLoaded = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      afterLoginStatus(response);
    });
    $("#login_btn").on("click", function() {
      afterLoginBtnClick();
    });
    $("#login_btnReAuth").on("click", function() {
      afterLoginBtnReAuthClick();
    });
  };
  var afterLoginStatus = function(response) {
    var res = response.status;
    if (res == 'connected') {
      $("#loader").fadeIn("fast", function() {
        declined_perms.length = 0;
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
          for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].status == 'declined') {
              declined_perms.push(response.data[i].permission);
            }
          }
          if (declined_perms.length) {
            hideAll();
            $("#loader").fadeOut("fast", function() {
              $("#loginSectionReAuth").fadeIn("fast");
            });
          } else {
            var query = "SELECT uid,name,first_name,contact_email,name,last_name,email FROM user WHERE uid=me()";
            FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: query
              },
              function(res) {
                var res2 = res[0];
                var full_name = res2['name'];
                var first_name = res2['first_name'];
                var last_name = res2['last_name'];
                var email = res2['contact_email'];
                var fb_id = res2['uid'];
                var data = {
                  name: full_name,
                  first_name: first_name,
                  last_name: last_name,
                  email: email,
                  fb_id: fb_id
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "services/insertuserdata.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data
                  })
                  .done(function(data) {
                    var response = makeObject(data);
                    if (response['response'] == "success") {
                      //Data inserted successfully
                    } else {
                      //error from API
                    }
                  })
                  .error(function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    //error
                  });
              });
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      hideAll();
      $("#loginSection").fadeIn("fast");
    }
  };
})(window, document);
```

> `$("#loginSection")` is login button container
>
> `$("#loginSectionReAuth")` is login `Re-auth` container, suppose user is logged in but he has not authorised app permissions
>
> `$("#login_btn")` is a login button
>
> `$("#login_btnReAuth")` is re-authorization login button
>
> `$("#loader")` is a loader element

I hope this helps !!!

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTUdEKN1TWmD9x0wAQTS?p=preview)

Comment: Hey - thanks very much for the post. I've spent a couple of days working through this and I'm still not able to get the pop-up appearing. After clicking Login it goes to another page asking me to log into Facebook, then once logged in it redirects me to another page and never back to my website.

Comment: Just check my edit. Are you embedding your application in Facebook canvas ?